# IntelliJ - Project tab only shows .gitignore file and not project structure

Tags: java, intellij-idea, version-control

I have a problem with my IntelliJ project. After adding VCS to my project, the project structure in the "Project" tab is not visible any more.

Here is what it looks like right now:

[image: problem]

Other projects work fine and everything is visible (eg. "src" folder, .java files...)

Can someone help?
Thanks

Comment: you have deleted the intellij workplace xml files

Comment: How to get it back?

Comment: try adding project again , you'll notice it'll create a hidden directory with it's config files.

Comment: exactly what kind of project is it??? Maven /gradle?

Comment: you saved my life. :D You can write your answer as a official answer so I can approve it.

Comment: it happened with me a couple of days back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You have deleted the intellij workplace hidden xml files**

**You'll need to import project again to intellij**

Creating a project by importing the sources from Bnd/Bndtools, Eclipse, Flash Builder, Gradle, or Maven

1. If no project is currently open in IntelliJ IDEA, click Import Project on the Welcome screen. Otherwise, select File | New | Project from Existing Sources.
2. In the dialog that opens, select the directory or file which you want to use as a source of import. This may be a directory that contains the corresponding collection of sources or a file that appropriately describes such a collection. (The possible choices are listed right in the dialog.) Click OK.
3. On the first page of the wizard, specify the origin of the sources. (This page is not shown if IntelliJ IDEA has guessed what you are importing.) Select Import project from external model, and select Bnd/Bndtools, Eclipse, Flash Builder, Gradle, or Maven. Click Next.

Ref:https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-a-project-by-importing-existing-sources.html